# Using a string literal works but passing as arguments does not

Tags: node.js, powershell, ffmpeg

I am passing string literals to my powershell script as follows:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
            child;
  child = spawn("powershell.exe", [
            "./scripts/ffmpeg_convert.ps1",
            `./cache/videos/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`,
            ` ./cache/converted_videos/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`
          ]);
```

Where spawn is part of node.js [Spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows)

And my **powershell script** is as follows:

```
param(
    [string]$originFile = $Args[0],
    [string]$outputFile = $Args[1]
)
echo "Moving moov atom"
ffmpeg -i $originFile -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags +faststart $outputFile
```

But, the script will not execute with the argument of

`./cache/videos/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`

However, if I change the argument out for the literal string let's say
`./cache/videos/inputVideo.mov`

it executes just fine.

This is really making me scratch my head.

I created two test scripts that work with the same principal... So is it just the way `${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}` is being translated? And with that being said, if I echo the arguments they are as expected.

**Script 1**

```
 ./convert_videos.ps1 ./inputVideo.mov outputVideo.mov
```

**Script 2**

```
 param(
    [string]$originFile = $Args[0],
    [string]$outputFile = $Args[1]
)
echo "Moving moov atom"
ffmpeg -i $originFile -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags +faststart $outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into issues with how your parameters are declared in your Powershell script. Try the following:

```
param(
    [Parameter(position = 0)]
    [string]$originFile,

    [Parameter(position = 1)]
    [string]$outputFile
)

# For debugging, check the values in PS
echo "Moving moov atom. originFile: $originFile. outputFile: $outputFile. Working Directory: $((Get-Location).Path)"
ffmpeg -i $originFile -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags +faststart $outputFile
```

You can also name the parameters when calling the script in a more Powershell-y way, though this will not affect your script execution, it looks nicer to those of us immersed in Powershell :)

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
        child;
child = spawn("powershell.exe", [
        "./scripts/ffmpeg_convert.ps1",
        "-originFile",
        `./cache/videos/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`,
        "-outputFile",
        ` ./cache/converted_videos/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`
      ]);
```

Comment: I implemented both suggestions at it yielded the same result =[

Comment: Edited to add some debug output in the Powershell.

Comment: `Powershell Data: Moving moov atom. originFile: ./cache/videos/1556902852765.mov outputFile: ./cache/converted_videos/1556902852765.mov`

Comment: Maybe a problem with your working directory? I'm running out of ideas. Edited to add yet more debugging info.

Comment: Also, what are the results? Is there an exception, or does the new file just not get created?

Comment: `Powershell Data: Moving moov atom. originFile: ./cache/videos/1556903432950.mov. outputFile: ./cache/converted_videos/1556903432950.mov. Working Directory: C:\Users\Wade Aston\Desktop\STEMuli\server`

The cache folder is:
`C:\Users\Wade Aston\Desktop\STEMuli\server/cache`

thanks for trying man, i've been going nuts for like 3 days with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192804/discussion-between-kpogue-and-user10204157).

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious problem with your code is that **there's a *leading space* in the template literal that is passed as the last argument**.

This leading space is retained as part of the argument, which presumably invalidates the path.

Therefore, replace:

```
` ./cache/converted_videos/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`
```

with:

```
`./cache/converted_videos/${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`
```

---

Two asides:

- Instead of using `${tempFileName + "."}${videoType}`, consider using the simpler `${tempFileName}.${videoType}`
- In your PowerShell script, there is no point in assigning `= $Args[0]` and `= $Args[1]` as default values for your parameters. If you do specify arguments when the script is called, they are bound positionally by default; if you don't, the corresponding `$Args` element will be empty.

Comment: `./cache/videos/$($tempFileName + ".")${videoType}`,

then if I echo:
` ./cache/videos/.mov`

Comment: @user10204157: Sorry, I mistook your JavaScript template literals for PowerShell code. I did spot a problem in your code, however - please see my updated answer.